# Interval :30 loop each array

Tags: javascript

In Javascript how to make loop if is `<=4` that returns array of data:

```
["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:30", "4:00"]
```

This is for example interval time ":30".

Example:

```
for (var i=0; i<=4; i++) {
  a[i] = i.toString() + ":00";
  a[i+1] = i.toString() + ":30";
}
```

Comment: I don't get it ... please try to be more exact. Do you want to loop over the array? Do you want a loop to create the array for a given max hour??

Comment: Your question is really unclear

Comment: Also: Show us your code so far

Comment: It's duration and infinity. Only arrays.

Comment: Do you use Google translator? Please don't

Comment: Your exaple, but `a[2*i] = ...; a[2*i+1] = ...;` is an answer

Comment: Resolved: `      a[2*i] = i.toString() + ":00";      a[2*i+1] = i.toString() + ":30";  Thx @Ilya

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i<=4; i++) 
{
  a[2 * i]     = i + ":00";
  a[2 * i + 1] = i + ":30";
}
```

but this solution will include `04:30`

To get around this problem you can use next code:

```
for (var i=0; i<=8; i++) 
{
  var prefix = i % 2 == 0 ? ":00" : ":30";
  a[i] = Math.floor(i / 2) + prefix;
}
```

Comment: This will include 04:30

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0 ; i < 4; i++) {
  arr[j] = i.toString() + ":00";
  if (j < 4)
    arr[j+1] = i.toString() + ":30";
  j += 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates

```
["0:00", "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00", "2:30", "3:00", "3:30", "4:00", "4:30"]
```

So you only want to exclude the last step?

```
var maxhour = 4
for (var i=0; i<(2*maxhour); i+=2) {
  a[i] = i.toString() + ":00";
  if(i<maxhour)
     a[i+1] = i.toString() + ":30";
}
```